# IE7 fails on slideToggle if the font-style is italic?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/deaKa/6/) code :

HTML

```
<a href="/link/" id="camereRichiedi">Go</a>

<div id="camereInformazioni">
    <div id="richiediInfo" class="richiedi_info">
        <div class="label">
            Name
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="field_name">
        </div>

        <div class="label">
            Surname
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" name="field_surname">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#camereRichiedi').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#richiediInfo').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

CSS

```
.richiedi_info
{
    position:relative;
    width:470px;
    display:none;
}

.richiedi_info .label
{
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    height:34px;
    font-style:italic;    
}

.richiedi_info .field
{
    width:360px;
    float:left;
    height:34px;
}
```

So, if I click on Go, on every browsers (Chrome, firefox, IE8+, expect IE7) I'll see the "labels" near the input field (Name and Surname).

On IE7 I can only see them if I remove `font-style:italic;` from the `.richiedi_info .label` CSS class.

A jQuery's bug? Or where am I wrong here?

Comment: I'm sure this question doesn't have any responses cause none of us are on IE7 lol but by looking at the code I see your using float's which can have some weird effects cause it causes the object not to be a box model.  Try adding `display: inline-block;` to your `.richiedi_info .label` class and/or take out your float's and code it a different way using inline-block divs/spans/etc...

Comment: IE rocks as a browser! Hope they'll change some cross-browser issues. It's a unique browser most web developers have problems.

Comment: @Jeff Wilbert : "none of us are on IE7"? That's shame man! XP support only IE7-, and tons of users in the world use XP. So making a website without check on IE7 it's wrong IMO! `display: inline-block;` it is not cross-browser.

Comment: @markzzz I'm sure there are some that still use IE7, like I'm sure some people are on Windows 98 still but come on... there's a point you reach where its not feasible or reasonable to code support for older devices; most of the time you just hindering yourself.  FYI [IE8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) does support XP and has been around for 2 and half years already...

Comment: Uhm, 98=SP2/SP3 , I'll bet less people upgrade theirs computers. It also depends the target of your website : hotel/residence/tourism or personal webpage? Think about...

Answer (score 2):

There's a [known bug](http://www.cayenne.co.uk/ie7/disappearing-content.html) in IE7 which affects italic text rendering. It doesn't seem to exactly match your problem but I'd bet it's related.

As a general rule of thumb, when IE* starts being naughty, the first thing I do is put `zoom: 1;` on the containing element; this forces it to "have layout" and often fixes the problem. Here's [some more info on "having layout" in IE](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Comment: Also you can trying redefine css attributes again  --> http://jsfiddle.net/deaKa/15/